# simple buck converter not working

Tags: microcontroller, buck

I have [this buck converter circuit](https://ia801501.us.archive.org/11/items/Untitled_20180117/Untitled.png). the mcu is stm32f0 ,prescaler 16 , period 300 , low polarity state .
 when i put any number % of duty cycle (pulse 'ccr') the output get 7.8v fixed . why?? 
[image: Schematic]

Comment: the image   :   https://ia801501.us.archive.org/11/items/Untitled_20180117/Untitled.png

Comment: Crop that image and include it in your question, also **edit** your question instead of commenting on it.

Comment: greenearth73@yahoo.com (from the internet archive's metadata to your image) PLEASE don't abuse the internet archive as your image hosting platform. Use imgur.com, as the website's image upload works through that, anyway.

Comment: *the output get 7.8v fixed* What do you expect to happen and why?

Comment: There's no way anyone can solve this without more information. You need to show the circuit, the measurement method, confirm signals at other points, describe the GPIO configuration, etc., etc. You'll need to show a lot more work upfront to warrant much help.

Answer (score 1):

OP's diagram: -

[image]

The problem is that you are expecting to drive a high side P channel MOSFET from a 3 volt IO pin from an MCU. This won't happen and the MOSFET will appear to be on all the time. Any volt drop you get between input supply and output side is due to output loads you have connected and series resistance in the 100 uH inductor. If you have no loads connected then maybe your 9 volts input supply has drooped to 7.8 volts.

In its simplest form a P channel MOSFET can be driven from the low side like this: -

[image]

The ON/OFF signal would be where you connect the PWM from your MCU and you would connect to it via a resistor of about 1 kohm. If your PWM switching frequency is > 10 kHz then you need to take care of other things like the gate-source capacitance of the MOSFET slowing the output of T1 down. There is a heap of things to consider when you look into it.

Comment: The high side switch will work provided the GPIO is open collector. I would also add a protection circuit (say resistor + Zener) to protect the GPIO when in the high state, but technically the internal protection diodes will work for a while anyway. But there's a million other things that could be wrong too.

Comment: Well maybe you could point to somewhere in the mcu spec that states that an open collector output will withstand 9 volts. @HeathRaftery.

Comment: lol, okay. Figure 16 on pg 133 of RM0360 shows the PMOS in circuit between the pin and the Vdd rail. PMOS have a body diode which will conduct excess voltage on the pin, clamping the pin to <4V. The 10kR in the external circuit will limit current. Those familiar with the STM32 will tell you that this provides withstand ability, but as I said in my comment, I'd add a protection circuit anyway.